# Given f(x) is a polynomial function of x satisfying

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

$f(x)\cdot f(y)=f(x)+f(y)+f(xy)-2$, $f(2)=5$, then $f(3)=?$

My attempt is as follows:-

**Finding $f(1)$**

$$f(1).f(2)=f(1)+f(2)+f(2)-2$$
$$5f(1)=f(1)+10-2$$
$$4f(1)=8$$
$$f(1)=2$$

**Finding $f(0)$**
$$f(0).f(2)=f(0)+f(2)+f(0)-2$$
$$5f(0)=2f(0)+5-2$$
$$3f(0)=3$$
$$f(0)=1$$

**Finding $f(3)$**
$$f(0).f(3)=f(0)+f(3)+f(0)-2$$
$$f(3)=f(0)+f(3)+f(0)-2$$
$$0=0$$

**Let's take the help of $f(1)$**
$$f(1).f(3)=f(1)+f(3)+f(3)-2$$
$$2f(3)=2f(3)+2-2$$
$$0=0$$

**Let's take the help of $f(2)$**
$$f(2).f(3)=f(2)+f(3)+f(6)-2$$
$$5f(3)=5+f(3)+f(6)-2$$
$$4f(3)=3+f(6)$$

But we don't $f(6)$

I am not seeing any way to calculate $f(3)$. Any suggestions?

Comment: We can rewrite the equation to be $$(f(x)-1)\cdot(f(y)-1)=f(xy)-1$$

Comment: yah, but how it helps

Comment: actually I calculated $f(0),f(1)$, but not able to calculate $f(3)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that if $g(x)=f(x)-1$, then $g(2)=4$ and $$g(x)\cdot g(y)=g(xy)$$This relation implies that $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$.

So, we know that for all $n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$, $g(2^n)=2^{2n}$. There is only one polynomial that satisfies this, which is $g(x)=x^2$ (if two polynomials agree on infinitely many points, their difference is also a polynomial, which can't have infinitely many roots unless it is trivial). So, $$f(x)=x^2+1$$

Comment: sorry didn't get you, can you explain in simple terms, from where you got $g(x)$

Comment: $g (x)=f(x)-1$.

Comment: how you got $g(2^n)=2^{2n}$?

Comment: $g(2)=4$ is the base case, $g(2^{n-1})\cdot g(2) = g(2^n)=4\cdot g(2^{n-1})$.

Comment: may be $g(2)$ is 4 because g(x) can be 2x, how can you be sure that  g(x)=x^2

Comment: @user3290550 Since we have infinitely many points that agree with $g(x)=x^2$, and two polynomials that agree on infinitely many points are equal. Hence, $g(x)=x^2$ is the only solution.

Comment: yeah so my question is that so do you know that g(x)=x^2 at infinitely many points?

Comment: @user3290550 That's the whole $g(2^n)$ thing.